# Number of ways in which one can start from any node and return to it in K steps (complete graph)

Tags: graph-theory, recurrence-relations

Given two integers N & K, consider a complete graph(every pair of distinct vertices is connected by a unique edge.) of N nodes. Calculate the number of ways in which one can start from any node and return to it in K steps. Output answer % 1000000007.

Here's the link to the question.

https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/pablo-safe-houses/

How to solve this question?Also in the editorial section it is mentioned that it can be solved using Matrix Exponentiation, what would be the recurrence relation?

Comment: @bof
As I mentioned in the question itself, that it is mentioned in editorial section that it can be solved using matrix exponentiation, thus it must have some recurrence relation.Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is not clear to me that the only possible use for matrix exponentiation lies in solving recurrence equations. For example, if $A=[a_{i,j}]$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, and if $A^k=[c_{i,j}],$ then one sees directly that $c_{i,j}$ is the number of walks of length k that start at vertex $v_i$ and end at vertex $v_j.$

Comment: @bof Using your comment you can also solve the question via any diagonal entry of $(P - I)^k$ which may be what this editorial section was hinting at? We can interpret the matrix $(P-I)$ as expressing a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the answer $f(n, k)$.

If you start and end from node $1$, you have $(k-1)$ choices to make for the intermediate nodes since you lose a choice for the last day. For each intermediate choice, you have $n-1$ options. This would yield $(n-1)^{k-1}$ but then we have to remove all the choices that have the second to last entry as $1$. But we know these exactly as $f(n, k-1)$.

Your recurrence is $f(n,k) = (n-1)^{k-1} - f(n,k-1)$.
The base case is $f(n, 2) = n-1$.

Expanding out a couple of times you will begin to see a pattern. $f(n,k) = (n-1)^{k-1} - (n-1)^{k-2} + (n-1)^{k-3} ... (n-1)$

This expression looks something like this

`int total = 0;
int power_of_neg_n_minus_1 = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < k-1; ++i) {
    power_of_n_minus_1 *= -(n-1);
    total += power_of_neg_n_minus_1;
}
// just in case we got - + - + ... instead of + - + - ....
if (total < 0) { total *= -1 };`

The only problem here is that you will overflow the `int` so you need to take `%` inside the loop. Also you might need to be aware of the behavior of `%` on negative `int`s.

Comment: If I have not made a mistake here, you will probably want to expand the recurrence to see it as powers of $(n-1)$ so you can compute it efficiently inside a for loop.

Comment: The problem also asks for the answer modulo some large integer, which seems only to be because you will otherwise overflow a 64 bit integer. In this case you can repeatedly take the modulus at intermediate steps because the modulus operation is a homomorphism.

Comment: I understood the logic behind the recurrence relation you just formed but I'm not able to think of how to apply Matrix Exponentiation(I wonder even if it can solve this recurrence relation using matrix expo?). If you check the editorial section in the mentioned link, they have mentioned a formula(without giving any logic). We can use Modular Exponentiation to compute value for large values of N and K.

Comment: I believe you are confusing matrix exponentiation with exponentiation in modular arithmetic. In fact, there is not much to "solve" here. You just keep listing out the terms until it bottoms out. I will update the answer to show this.

Comment: Modular exponentiation is used when we are computing something like a raised to the power b modulo m, where b can be quite large(as linear exponentiation will not work, also using modulo to overcome overflow problem).

On other hand, Matrix Expo is used to solve recurrence relations like fibonacci which F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2).

Now, I'm trying to apply Matrix Expo to solve the recurrence relation given by you as values of N and K can be upto 10 raised to the power 18 and thus simple loop wouldn't work.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I see what you're getting at. You will not need matrix exponentiation in this case because the recurrence only depends on one prior term as opposed to Fibonacci sequence which depends on two prior terms. Also the recurrence is not linear in the previous terms. So unless I made a mistake, I don't think you will need matrix exponentiation.

Comment: The case with $k = 2$ is impossible since the question demands the criminal cannot visit the same place twice in a row.

Comment: if N=2 and k=2, starting from 1, we can go to 2(first step) and then back to 1(second step). generalizing, for k=2, we have n-1 ways.

Comment: Yes sorry I misinterpreted $k$ to mean the total number of days in question. But it looks like I made another mistake that cancelled out that error somehow.

Comment: Say, initially the person is at some node 'x'. after that he has 'K' more days and he needs to be at 'x' on the last day. So, I think intermediate choices should be k-1 not k-2 . Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes sorry, I hope I got it right now.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your time and help.Btw I would like to know where to study about these things.I would be highly grateful if you could provide links of some relevant resources.

Comment: @Divyanshu Note that $(n-1)^{k-1}-(n-1)^{k-2}+\cdots$ is a finite geometric series which can be evaluated explicitly: $$f(n,k)=\frac{(n-1)^k+(-1)^k(n-1)}n$$

Comment: Great observation! It should help the efficiency of the program greatly :)

Comment: Literally great work bof.Now this formula started making sense.Beauty of maths.Who would have thought Mark's observation would help us in justifying the formula.Thanks bof and Mark. I was stuck on this problem from a very long time.   :-)

Comment: Note to actually implement @bof 's formula you will have to find the inverse of $n$ mod 1000000007. Luckily 1000000007 is prime! Maybe you can come up with a very fast solution using this

Comment: We can easily find inverse using Euler's formula
A^-1 = A^(m-2) %m . Also to compute A^(m-2)%m, we will need modular exponentitation.

Comment: Re: resources for learning - this type of question falls under combinatorics and vaguely linear algebra. I used this book in college and I remember it being pretty good although the Amazon reviews are mixed https://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/0073229725/

Comment: @Divyanshu By the way, in my last comment, the numerator of the fraction $$\frac{(n-1)^k+(-1)^k(n-1)}n$$ is the [chromatic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) of the [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) $C_k,$ that is, the number of ways that the graph $C_k$ (with labeled nodes) can be properly colored (adjacent vertices must receive different colors) from a palette of $n$ colors. In your problem we divide by $n$ because the color of a certain vertex is fixed, i.e., Pablo is in city 1 on day 1.

Answer (score 1):

There was some talk about a recurrence relation and matrix exponentiation.

Let $n_{i, t}$ be the number of ways to get to node $i$ in $t$ steps. The recurrence is $n_{i,t} = n_{1, t-1} + n_{2, t-1} + ... + n_{N, t-1}$ where only $n_{i,t-1}$ does not appear on the left hand side since it is impossible to travel from $i$ to $i$ in one step.

Notating $n_{1, t} ... n_{N, t}$ as the $N$ dimensional vector $n_t$, the recurrence can be turned into a linear operator $n_t = (P - I)n_{t-1}$ where $P$ is the matrix of all ones and $P-I$ is the matrix of all ones except zeros on the diagonal.

The answer then is any term on the diagonal of $(P-I)^k$.